# To not treat files like 'vimrc-tips.txt' as Vim Script files

Tags: vimrc, filetype

There is a line in `defaults.vim` that enables Vim Script syntax for any `.txt` file with `vimrc` in its filename (for example, `vimrc-tips.txt`):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *vimrc*           call s:StarSetf('vim')
```

I want to replace `*vimrc*` with `*vimrc` or maybe even with a regular expression that will allow only the period or underscore as the first character.

For this, if  understnad correctly, I need to disable the original autocommand first.

I tried to disable it with

```
" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829710
augroup standard
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *vimrc* setlocal setfiletype disabled
augroup END
```

The idea is that this should disable treating files like `vimrc-tips.txt` as Vim Script files, but at the same time this should not disable syntax for `_vimrc`, `.vimrc`, or any other files (for example, `foo.md` or `bar.js`).

But this doesn't disable syntax for files like `vimrc-tips.txt`, and even worse when I open such a file, there is a message:

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

How this should be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The line in question is in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`, not in `defaults.vim`.
2. You can override it by creating the following file:

   ```
   ~/.vim/ftdetect/vimtxt.vim
   ```

   with this content:

   ```
   autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *vimrc*.txt setfiletype text
   ```

Note that the autocommand in the linked answer is broken.